# Option pattern delimiter in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a pattern that will match the given string, and create several groups from that string.

The input string:

```
Case 1: wp/video/video123/xyz/abc
Case 2: wp/video/video123
Case 3: wp/video
Case 4: wp
```

And the desired output:

```
Case1: group1=wp,group2=video,group3=video123
Case2: group1=wp,group2=video,group3=video123
Case3: group1=wp,group2=video
Case4: group1=wp
```

The pattern I have created is matching the first two cases, but ignores the last two cases:

```
(.*?)/+(.*?)/(.*?)[/.]
```

Comment: Something like this `([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)?)?)?`

Comment: Thanks # nhahtdh . It's working. Can you please explain me your answer.So that I can modify it according to my requirement in future

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, so I just throw some crap in the comment. How are you going to use this regex (`Matcher.find`)? Have you considered `String.split`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want without a regex using pure `String.Split` and then accessing the groups:

```
String input ="wp/video/video123/xyz/abc";
String[] spts = input.split("/");
System.out.println("group1=" + spts[0] + ";group2=" + spts[1] + ";group3=" + spts[2]);
```

This will output `group1=wp;group2=video;group3=video123` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/9mlA0R)).

If you need a regex solution, nhahtdh already provided you with a sample regex that uses optional non-capturing groups, but I also suggest consuming all the characters with `.*` at the end of the pattern, or we are going to get further matches with `xyz/abc`:

```
String str = "wp/video/video123/xyz/abc";
String rx = "([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)?)?)?.*";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("group1=" + m.group(1) + ",group2=" + m.group(2) + ",group3=" + m.group(3));
}
```

Regex explanation:

- `([^/]+)` - 1st group of 1 or more characters other than `/`
- `(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)?)?)?` - Optional capturing group that matches

  - `/` - literal `/`
  - `([^/]+)` - 2nd group of 1 or more characters other than `/`
  - `(?:/([^/]+)?)?` - Optional capturing group that matches the same content as described above
- `.*` - Match all characters but newline to the end of the string so that we do not get further matches. *Remove it* if you want to get further matches. Or replace with a `(?=\\s|$)` look-ahead to match before a space or end of string.

See another demo [here](https://ideone.com/AnHqs7)